# How to pass variable from one function to another, both with parameters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have several landing pages with call-to-action buttons ("Download the report", for example) and need to report through a URL string two variables from the actual button click (report title and report type and whether the visitor who is clicking the button is a new or existing client. The analytics company requires the final URL to be sent like this:

```
https://thisurl.html?assetName=" + assetName + "&assetType=" + assetType + "&custType=" + custType);
```

To gather the assetName and assetType, I've created this function, which has already been in production and works fine for reporting the assetName and assetType.

```
function tracker(assetName,assetType) {
  var fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://thisurl.html?assetName=" + assetName + "&assetType=" + assetType + "&custType=" + custType);
  if (typeof fileref!="undefined") {        
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
  }
```

}

Now, we need to also track whether the client is "new" or "current", so I have this function:

```
function cStatus(elem) {
    var els = [];
    while (elem) {
        els.unshift(elem);
        elem = elem.parentNode;
        if (elem.id == "new") {
            break;
        } else if (elem.id == "current") {
            break;
        }
    }
    custType = elem.id;
}
```

To clarify, the call-to-action button is included on the page twice, once in the "new" div and the other in the "current" div.

```
<div id="new">
...button code...
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="current">
...button code...
</div>
```

In order to create that URL string for reporting, my thinking is to use the "cStatus" function to identify the div id ('new' or 'current'), then use the cStatus function to get the info on the button click. The button has an onclick that passes the 'assetName' and 'assetType':

```
onclick="tracker('PDF','document.pdf')
```

The problem I'm having is getting all three of those variables into one function, so I can create the URL string for reporting. I've search and found solutions for functions without parameters, but cannot figure out how to pass a variable from one function with parameters "function cStatus(elem)" to another function with parameters "tracker(assetName, assetType), so that it can ultimately be passed along in a URL string for reporting.

Comment: Neither of those functions call the other. It doesn't make sense to talk about "passing" anything if there aren't any function calls involved.

Comment: You could use Global Variables ..... to share information

Comment: Or even better: a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Global variables are nearly always a bad idea, as they pollute the global namespace and give rise to the likelihood of naming clashes.

Comment: Do you mean that the two functions are asynchronous with respect to each other - ie, they run in different event threads?

Comment: This looks overly complicated. There's probably a totally different and easy solution but you don't really explain WHY you do it.

Comment: What exactly are you asking...?

Comment: Looking at what's provided, either `cStatus()` isn't giving you the value you want (try `console.log()` within the function to check yourself), or `cStatus()` isn't being called before `tracker()`. Or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question doesn't make to much sense, still, I guess you need a global variable, here's an example:

```
function func1(){
    window.myvar = "something";
}
```

Then get your global variable like this:

```
function func2(){
    var newvar = window.myvar + "append something";
}
```

---

Another option is to assign the variable outside the function scope, making it also global.

```
var myvar = "bla";
    
function func1(){
    myvar = "something";
}
     
function func2(){
    alert(myvar);
}
```

The value of `myvar` inside `func2` is now `something`

---

And finally, make your variable `Automatically Global` by assigning a value to it before being declared.

```
function func1(){
    myvar = "something";
}
```

The above will make `myvar` as a global variable, even if it is executed inside a function.

Learn more about [Scopes in JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could call one function from the other passing the parameters along.

```
function func1(param2){
  //do stuff with param2
}

function func2(param1){
   func1(param1);
}
```